# How to prevent periodicTimeObserver updating the progressBar while user drags the slider manually?

Tags: swift, avplayer, uislider

I have a periodicTimeObserver and it updates the elapsed and remaining timeLabels in the way I want, but the slider is jumping. How to prevent periodicTimeObserver updating the UISlider while user drags the slider manually?

[image: In this GIF you can see weird acting of the slider.]

This is my UISlider

```
private lazy var progressBar: UISlider = {
let v = UISlider()
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//v.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
v.isContinuous = false
return v
}()
```

Periodic time observer which updates the UISlider and the elapsed and remaining time labels.

```
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
    
if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
    
let currentTime : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
let totalTime : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentItem!.duration);

    self.progressBar.value = Float(currentTime)
    self.progressBar.minimumValue = 0
    self.progressBar.maximumValue = Float(totalTime)

 
    
self.elapsedTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: currentTime)
self.remainingTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeIntervalRemaining(interval: totalTime - currentTime)
```

The function that should seek to a point of the audio and update the time labels.

```
@objc func progressScrubbed(_ :UISlider) {
           
       let seconds : Int64 = Int64(self.progressBar.value)
       let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
       
           
           player!.seek(to: targetTime)
           
           if player!.rate == 0
           {
               play()
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know if user is interacting with a slider in order to ignore `PeriodicTimeObserver`. Moreover you need to reset `PeriodicTimeObserver` on each `seek`. So let's create a custom UISlider and override a one method:

```
class MySlider: UISlider {

    var onTouchesBegan: (() -> ())?
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        
        onTouchesBegan?()
    }

}
```

Now you can create a parameter which will track if slider is touched or not and set it in closures of `MySlider`:

```
private var isTouchingSlider: Bool = false

private lazy var progressBar: MySlider = {
    let v = MySlider()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.isContinuous = false
    
    v.onTouchesBegan = { [weak self] in
        self?.isTouchingSlider = true
    }
    
    return v
}()
```

And your periodic observer methods would look like this:

```
var periodicObserverToken: Any?

func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
    let interval = CMTime(
        seconds: 1,
        preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    )
    
    periodicObserverToken = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let `self` = self, let player = self.player, player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay, let currentItem = self.player.currentItem, !self.isTouchingSlider else { return }
        
        let currentTime : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime());
        let totalTime : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration);
        
        self.progressBar.value = Float(currentTime)
        self.progressBar.minimumValue = 0
        self.progressBar.maximumValue = Float(totalTime)
    }
}

private func removePeriodicTimeObserver() {
    guard let periodicObserverToken = periodicObserverToken else { return }
    player?.removeTimeObserver(periodicObserverToken)
    self.playerPeriodicTimeObserver = nil
}
```

You need to make all the necessary updates when slider is updated:

```
@objc func progressScrubbed(_ :UISlider) {
    let seconds : Int64 = Int64(self.progressBar.value)
    let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
    
    removePeriodicTimeObserver()
    isTouchingSlider = false
    player!.seek(to: targetTime)
    addPeriodicTimeObserver()
    
    if player!.rate == 0 {
        play()
    }
}
```